# JPA JPQL: select entities with List attribute

Tags: jpa, collections, jpql

I have an entity which have a collection of tags

```
@ManyToMany
private Set<Tag> listeTag;
```

I want to write a query which returns a list of my entity which contains all tags passed in parameters and not just one like this.

```
select distinct entity from Entity entity where and entity.listeTag  in :listeTag
```

if there are two tags in `listeTag` I want only entities which have at least the two tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select e from SomeEntity e where :numberOfTagsInSet = 
    (select count(tag.id) from SomeEntity e2 
     join e2.listeTag tag 
     where e.id = e2.id 
     and tag.id in :setOfTagIds)
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: It's quite simple actually. Let's say the tags you're looking for are foo and bar. The inner query counts the number of tags of e2 which are foo or bar. If the result is 2, then you know that e2 has tags foo and bar. The outer query returns all the entities where tis count is 2.

Comment: ok! i didn't think to try with a count. I try everything i can for two days. thanks again